Error: One or more duplicate file names were detected. All image filenames must be unique : edupay (Resources\AppIcon\edupay.png
I have a .NET MAUI project built using .NET 6. I am currently trying to upgrade the project to the latest .NET 8 version. I referred to the following link for guidance: Upgrading .NET MAUI from .NET 7 to .NET 8.
After following the steps successfully, there are no issues with the dependencies, and everything appears to be clean. However, when I attempt to rebuild the project, I encounter the following error:
Build Error
I have not been able to find any useful solutions for this issue, and my problem remains unresolved. Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated. Thanks!
Tried suggestions of deleting and recreating the images folder in resources/images path, but still getting that error.
Also tried to edit MAUI project cs file to include only specific file types by defining like this:
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images*.svg" />
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images*.png" />
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images*.jpg" />
Even this is not working and still i see this error.

Delete bin obj folders, and check if there is another image with the same name, you must check your class libraries (.dll) if exist, the name should be once in your entire solution.

Thank you for the response . I have certainly tried the above solution suggested by you but still the error persists. Please check the below images for the usages of the particular image that I am getting error in my MAUI Project. Usage
Usage

You're welcome, from those screenshots، I can confirm your issue when you setting <MauiInclude Include=...edupay.png use update instead of include and place it underneath the <MauiImage Include=...*

Note that, if you have an imagex.svg it will generates *.png

thanks for suggestion. The above suggestion works fine in removing the build errors. I would like to have a suggestion on one of the other build issue that I am facing now. [![Firebase and manifest error][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Z4507Jjm.png ......Any idea on how to resolve this?

You are welcome, regarding to the other issue on Firebase, check the version in NuGet must support/compatible with your targeting framework net8, because error showing net6, if not fixed, create a new question

I had a similar issue with the appicon.svg file, also in a .Net 8 Maui project. It turns out that having appicon.png in another folder is considered the same filename, even though the extensions are different.
After changing the name of one of the images, the error went away. I guess I'm too used to the extension being considered part of the filename, this making it distinct.

I just changed the the build action in the file properties to another and back to MauiIcon again. So the reference is set new and there is no longer an error.
